# No signature of method: com.crashlytics.tools.gradle.CrashlyticsPlugin On Mac

Tags: android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradle-plugin, crashlytics-android, fabric.io

Below error while gradle sync Failed in Mac.

```
CONFIGURE FAILED in 3s
ERROR: No signature of method: com.crashlytics.tools.gradle.CrashlyticsPlugin.findObfuscationTransformTask() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [Debug]
```

Project works fine in Windows

Comment: Please see my answer with explanation in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55214993/error-no-signature-of-method-com-crashlytics-tools-gradle-crashlyticsplugin-fi/55215131#55215131

Answer (score 51):

There seems to be a problem with the version "1.28.0" of "io.fabric.tools:gradle".

I corresponded as follows

`classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'`

Change to the following code

`classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.27.1'`

I hope the fabric team will respond

Comment: I added these changes to android/app/build.gradle

Answer (score 31):

Its problem with fabric tools that added in **build.gradle** app level

To solve this issue

go to **build.gradle** **app** level and find the below code

change this

```
 dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
```

to this

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.27.1'
}
```

try with other versions like 1.28 if above version not working.
avoid using **+** in version codes and also that stops the auto update.

Comment: @rajesh vinnew. Can you tell me why its was working earlier, but suddenly it stopped any official links.

Comment: These much upvotes on this same answer proves that developers are too lazy

Comment: you made my day

Comment: Excellent! This answer resolved my Android build issue.

Answer (score 7):

In my case, the Gradle Build Task was failing with the latest version(1.28.0) of Fabric Gradle Plugin. Downgrading to version 1.27.1 resolved this issue. There has been a  [Fabric Gradle Plugin release](https://docs.fabric.io/android/changelog.html#march-15-2019) recently on 15th March 2019.

For users facing this issue and have added the Fabric Gradle Plugin as

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
        ...

}
```

need to replace with

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.27.1'
        ...

}
```