# ERROR: No signature of method: com.crashlytics.tools.gradle.CrashlyticsPlugin.findObfuscationTransformTask()

Tags: android, build-error, crashlytics-android, android-studio-3.3, build-variant

I am getting the following error while trying to build my project on Android Studio:

> ERROR: No signature of method:
>   com.crashlytics.tools.gradle.CrashlyticsPlugin.findObfuscationTransformTask()
>   is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values:
>   [DevDebug]

How to solve this?

Comment: Many people reported this error on, Fabric crashlytic. They are working on this.

Comment: Post your app level build.gradle code.

Comment: Thank you @VirajPatel. I have found a work-around for now. I had added the classpath dependency in my project level gradle file.

Comment: Thank you so much @HiteshTarbundiya. Hope they come out with a solution very soon. Anyways, I have currently downgraded to 1.27.1 and this seems to solve the issue for now.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/28416021/5022374 . this could help you.

Answer (score 112, accepted):

**EDIT: Before proceeding to the solution below, please at first update to the latest stable version of fabric gradle tools and check if the problem is fixed. At the time of this edit, some claim that updating to version 1.31.2 has fixed the issue.**

This seems to be an issue related to version "1.28.0" of `"io.fabric.tools:gradle"`.

Usually this kind of problem occurs if `groupId:artifactId:n.+` structure of versioning is used inside dependency (app level/project level). In this case:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
}
```

Because it auto updates the version, and as a result, if there is any fatal error in the latest version, the project is likely to face a crash due to build/runtime error.

**Android Studio always suggests: 'Avoid using `+` in version numbers; can lead to unpredictable and unrepeatable builds...'**

One working solution was found to be downgrading to a specific previous version like 1.27.1 or any other stable latest version prior to 1.28.0, like:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.27.1'
}
```

Remember to check both gradle files (app level/project level) to see where the above dependency has been declared and change accordingly.

Comment: Working fine for me

Answer (score 58):

hey this error raised because of Many android developers uses

`classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'`

like this so that compiler not find exactly match of the fabric version and error raise and also *M. Arabi Hasan Sakib* is right

`classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.28.0'`

also raise this type of error, solution mentioned by *M. Arabi Hasan Sakib* is also working. I tried below code and its working for me hope it works for you people also or just replace the line like

`classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.27.1'`:

(Put this code into the build.gradle in app directory)

```
  buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.27.1'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    maven {
        url "http://dl.bintray.com/lukaville/maven"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @MaheshKeshvala for your solution, but I think this issue is being generated not because '...compiler not find exactly match of the fabric version and error raise...' but because it is pointing to the latest version that is 1.28.0 and that has a known bug in it. However, I had downgraded to a previous version before posting this question and that helped. So, I wanted to share that solution by posting the issue. Thanks again :-)

Comment: yes @M.ArabiHasanSakib you are right and i mentioned in my answer also that your answer is right but i io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+ fabric version and error raise so that i write that compiler are not able to compile mixed versions like 1.+ or any other. Thanks for your answer its valuable for those who face this type of error.

Comment: I have all that content but mine still wouldn't build.

Comment: I'm getting the same error as the original question. I fixed it by editing my two build.gradle files to  'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.27.1' not just the one on the app directory.

Comment: @KishorPawar I suggest you to use latest version of the fabric 1.31.2.
Fabric resolve all the old problems into this latest version.